# Adding variations to dataLayer in WooCommerce (Add to cart event)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, google-datalayer

I'm using the code below which works great for simple products but doesn't log multiple variations when selected and added to cart. How can I modify the code so that the specific variations get pushed to the datalayer?

```
<?php
$product = wc_get_product( $post );
$terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
$term = $terms && $terms[0]->name != 'all' ? $terms[0]->name : $terms[1]->name;
?>
<script>
window.dataLayer.push({
  event: 'pin_cart',
  value: <?php echo $product->get_price(); ?>,
  currency: 'CAD',
  order_quantity: 1,
  line_items: [{
    product_name: '<?php echo $product->get_name(); ?>',
    product_id: <?php echo $product->get_id(); ?>,
    product_category: '<?php echo $term; ?>'
  }]
});
</script>
```